# How to make whenever i press button it turns from transparent to white and press again to turn it back from white to transparent?

Tags: html, jquery, css

```
#white1{
    background-color: white;
}

#mainNav {
    background-color: #ffffff00;
  /*background-color: #212529;*/

}
```

jquery

```
     $(document).ready(function(){    
  $(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
  if ($("#mainNav").css("background-color") != $("#white1").css("background-color")){
    $("#mainNav").css("background-color", "white");
    }else{
  $("#mainNav").css("background-color", "#ffffff00");
  }
  });
});
```

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top " id="mainNav">
<div class="container">

  <img src="http://www.astrixpt.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/logo_last1.png" class="img-responsive navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    list
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </button>
```

i want the standard nav bar to be transparent, whenever i click on "list" button the navbar the list opens and background turns into white and when to click on button "list" again to close the list i want the navbar to turn transparent again

but the problem is when i press on the buttons once it goes from transparent to white and no matter how many i press again it stays white

Comment: missing `mainNav` html

Comment: @Mech I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toggleClass`. The `background-color` is blue when it's clicked, transparent when it isn't.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navbar-toggler").click(function() {
      $("#mainNav").toggleClass("white1");
  });
});
```

```css
#mainNav {
  transition: background .5s ease-in;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.white1 {
  background-color: blue !important;
  transition: background .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top " id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">

    <img src="http://www.astrixpt.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/logo_last1.png" class="img-responsive navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    list
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </button>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! another thing is how i can add a transition everytime i click on it for example to fade?

Comment: Glad to help :) I added the code to my answer to transition in / out. I changed the color to blue so the change is more apparent.

Comment: is there an explanation why my first approach didn't work though?

Comment: you are comparing two things that should not be compared against one another in your if statement.